# What is wrong with my 'counterexample' to the Blichfeldt Lemma?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We used a simplified version of the Blichfeldt lemma in our class, as follows:

*Lemma:* Let $T \subset \mathbb R^n$ bounded with $V(T)>1$ ($n$-dimensional Volume). Then there exist $X',X'' \in T$, $X' \neq X''$ which satisfy $X' - X'' \in \mathbb Z^n$.

I think I found something 'counterexample' to that theorem in $n = 2$:
The gray area is certainly greater than one (width is 0.25 and height 4.25) and it is placed right in the middle of two 'columns' of $\mathbb Z^2$. I think you cannot find two points $X', X''$ in the gray area whose difference lies on a point of $\mathbb Z^2$ (The fat points are $\mathbb Z^2$ and the thin ones are just 0.25 steps.) My thought was that even the differences of the $x$-coordinates cannot even lie on one of the grid points.

[image]

What is wrong with this counterexample?

EDIT: For those who wonder how the image was generated: It was made with [MetaPost](http://www.tlhiv.org/mppreview/) using the code:

`u := 2cm;
path p;
for i =0 upto 3:
for j =0 upto 4:
draw (i,j)*u withpen pencircle scaled 0.1cm;
endfor;
endfor;
for i =0 upto 13:
for j =0 upto 18:
draw (i,j)*u/4 withpen pencircle scaled 0.03cm;
endfor;
endfor;
p = (1.5-0.125,0)*u--(1.5+0.125,0)*u--(1.5+0.125,4.25)*u--(1.5-0.125,4.25)*u--cycle;
fill p withcolor .8*white;
draw p;
label.bot("0.25",(1.5,0)*u);
label.lrt("4.25",(1.5+0.124,1.5)*u);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think just found out what is wrong, I had a wrong 'image' of $X'-X''$ in my mind:

If you consider the bottom left point as $(0,0)$ and if you take the points $(1.5,1)$ and $(2.5,1)$ you get the differences $(1,0)$ or $(-1,0)$ who both are certainly on the grid.

Comment: Correct! You are right.